# The system of differential equations is in steady state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

We have a system of non-homogeneous differential equations $$X'=AX+B$$

What does it mean that the system is in steady state??

$X$ is the vector $\begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \\ x_3(t)\end{pmatrix}$, $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $B$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix.

$$$$

Comment: Steady state means, when there's no time dependence in equations any more, so if your case, I suppose, time is the only variable, so you need to solve $X' = AX + B = 0$.

Comment: what do these letters stand for?

Comment: I added some information about what $X$, $A$ and $B$ stand  for... @abel

Comment: Is it as followed?? $$X'=0 \Rightarrow AX+B=0 \Rightarrow AX=-B \Rightarrow X=-A^{-1}B$$ @Kaster

Comment: The formula for $X(t)$ in your question implies that $X(t)\to X_\infty$ with $$X_\infty=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{590}{11}+\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
\frac{780}{11}-\frac{55}{\sqrt{3}}\\ 
\frac{335}{11}-\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{pmatrix}.$$ but on the other hand you say that you computed the steady state as $$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{545}{11} \\ \frac{645}{11} \\ \frac{515}{11}\end{pmatrix}.$$
These results are not compatible.

Comment: Which of them is wrong?? @Did Did I calculated wrong the real solution of the initial value probelm?? Or have I done a mistake at the calculation of $X=A^{-1}(-B)$ ??

Comment: ?? Why don't you look?

Comment: Your matrix inverse looks seems correct, I checked this with a computer, and you can do the same; it's more likely that your "full" solution is incorrect.

Comment: Ok... I try to calculate again the solution... @KenWei

Comment: I added in my initial post the way I calculated the solution... Could you take a look at it?? I tried several times to find the solution and each time I get an other result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... @KenWei

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your matrix of eigenvectors: notice that the matrix $A$ is symmetric, so you should have $K^{-1}=K^T$ if the eigenvectors in $K$ are normalized. But if your inversion is correct, then perhaps your eigenvectors are wrong (I did not calculate any of the eigenvectors/values myself, I only deduced that your matrices $K$ and $K^{-1}$ cannot be correct because $A$ is symmetric!)

Comment: Ok... I edited my initial post again... Could you take a look at it? @KenWei

Comment: (1,1,1) is indeed an eigenvector; 0.5774 is in fact $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ and is the components of the normalized eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\frac{1}{2}$ (up to a sign; you can just as well take the negative of this vector). So $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} (1,1,1)$ is the first column of $K$ (and first row of $K^T$). You can do similar for the other eigenvectors.

Comment: Ok...I added the calculation of the second eigenvector... Could you take a look?? @KenWei

Comment: Yes, it looks right. Try finding the third one now, and you have $K$, hence $K^T$ and then solve the problem as you did earlier and see if the constant term matches the answer.

Comment: So, before we make these vectors as the column of $K$ we have to normalize them, right?? @KenWei

Comment: Yes, because $K^{-1}=K^T$ is only true for orthogonal matrices.

Comment: I added the matrix $K$ at my initial post... Could you take a look at it and tell me if it is the right one?? @KenWei

Comment: It doesn't look orthogonal to me: if you take the dot product between the second and third column, if I'm seeing this right, the first two terms add to zero, which is a problem because the third is clearly not zero, and you need this dot product to be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the solution to the univariate differential equation $$x'(t)=-ax(t)$$ for $a>0$, which is $x(t)=x_0e^{-at}$. As $t$ grows large, $x(t) \to 0$. Then we call $0$ the steady state of $x(t)$. This is a sort of fixed point: if you begin at the steady state (if it exists), then your solution does not change in time, i.e. $x'(t)=0$. (For this example, that would mean $x_0=0$)

(It's essentially the same for higher spatial dimensions.)

Comment: Is it as followed?? $$X'=0 \Rightarrow AX+B=0 \Rightarrow AX=-B \Rightarrow X=-A^{-1}B$$ Or have I understood it wrong??

Comment: Yes, the answer you give is the steady state of the system.

Comment: I found now the correct solution of the system... I added it in my initial post... I am asked in how many hours the system reaches the steady state... How do we find this??

Comment: Can we find it numerically??

Answer (score 1):

the non homogenous equation $$x' = Ax + b \tag 1$$ sometimes has a constant solution $x = x_\infty.$ by the very definition, it must satisfy $$Ax_\infty + b = 0 \tag 2 $$ the equation $(2)$ may or may not have a solution. if all the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ has negative real part and $b$ does not grow badly, then the solutions of $(1)$ approach $x_\infty$ as $t\to \infty.$

if system is ever in steady state it means $$x(t) = x_\infty , \,  \forall t.  $$

Comment: The values of the vector $X$ at the steady state is the result of $X=A^{-1}(-B)$, right?? To find in how many hours the system reached the steady state do we have to find the solution of the system, set this equal to $A^{-1}(-B)$ and solve for $t$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar,   by uniqueness, the system will never reach a steady state in finite time if it did not start in one.

Comment: I added some information in my initial post about the problem that I am lookig at... Could you take a look at it??

Comment: @MaryStar, i don't understand why you are finding the solutions. i get $(50.673, 62.019, 48.509)^\top$ for the steady state. like i said steady state cannot be reached in finite time.

Comment: I had made a mistake at the calculation of $A^{-1}$. I edited it now... But I still don't get the same result as yours... The vector $(50.673, 62.019, 48.509)^\top$ is the vector $X$, isn't it??

Comment: @MaryStar, yes. just as in my previous comment.

Comment: Did you find the same $A^{-1}$ as I did??

Comment: @MaryStar, i did not find $A^{-1},$  i solved $Ax = b$ by row reducing the augmented matrix ${A|b].$

Comment: Ahaaa... Ok... I added in my initial post the way I calculated the solution of the real value problem... Could you take a look at it?? I tried several times to find the solution and each time I get an other result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You will ease the task by using an auxiliary variable that absorbs the steady-state.

$$X'(t)=AX(t)+B=A(X(t)+A^{-1}B),$$
so that with $Y(t)=X(t)+A^{-1}B$,
$$Y'(t)=AY(t),$$
and the steady-state condition is just $Y(\infty)=0$, i.e. $X(\infty)=-A^{-1}B$.

Now the solution of the homogenous equation is

$$Y(t)=e^{At}Y_0=Pe^{Dt}P^{-1}Y_0,$$
where $P$ is a matrix of Eigenvectors of $A$ and $D$ a diagonal matrix of Eigenvalues.

As in this case the Eigenvalues are real negative, the solution can be expressed as the sum of three negative exponentials, 
$$Y(t)=e^{d_0t}U+e^{d_1t}V+e^{d_2t}W,$$

and it can be approximated for large $t$ as the term with the slowest decay*,

$$Y(t)\approx e^{d_2t}U.$$

The system "reaches" the steady state when, say only $1\%$ of the transitory signal remains, i.e. when

$$d_2t\approx\ln(0.01).$$

---

*Unless the initial conditions are such that this term is missing or very small.

Comment: I found now the correct solution of the system... I added it in my initial post... Could you explain to me further the part about the time needed so that the system reaches the steady state...

Comment: Can we find the time numerically??

Comment: @MaryStar: the steady state is never exactly reached, it takes infinite time. You have to provide a criterion for quasi-steady state.

Comment: What kind of criterion do you mean??

Comment: Check what your instructor told you about this. Otherwise, the time is infinite.

Comment: Ok... I will check that... I have also an other question... I changed a little the system in my initial post... I am asked to find the values of $g_i$ so that the value of $x_3$ is greater that $x_1$ in the steady state... How do we find these values??